# What's the advantage of making your appengine app thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

I have an appserver that is getting painfully complicated in that it has to buffer data from incoming requests then push those buffers out, via pubsub, after enough has been received. The buffering isn't the problem, but efficient locking is... hairy, and I'm concerned that it's slowing down my service. I'm considering dropping thread safety in order to remove all the locking, but I'm worried that my app instance count will have to double (or more) to handle the same user load.

My understanding is that a threadsafe app is one where each thread is a billed app instance. In other words, I get billed for two instances by allowing multiple threads to run in a process, with the only advantage being that the threads can share memory and therefore, have a smaller overall footprint.

So to rephrase, does a multithreaded app instance handle multiple simultaneous connections, or is each billed app instance a separate thread - only capable of handling one request at a time? If I remove thread safety, am I going to need to run a larger pool of app instances?

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is not related to billing in any way - you still pay for one instance even if 10 threads are running in parallel on that instance.

Comment: Typically, yes. But since you are talking about locking and such, I feel there maybe room to improve your existing code.

Comment: I'm filling a number of different buffers, depending upon the data being queued. When a buffer is full (or beyond a certain age), I push it out via pubsub. Each buffer has its own lock and is only locked while being altered. If an instance is servicing multiple, simultaneous requests, there's a good chance that there's some blocking going on (there are a lot of buffers, but 2-4 of them are VERY high-traffic.) If I find that I must flush to pubsub, I don't do so while holding the lock. I publish a reference to the buffer, having replaced the buffer with an empty list while holding the lock.

Comment: It's hard to give any advice without knowing all the details, but can you use a shared Memcache instead? You can make async calls to Memcache, and return immediately. Another option is to create a task for updating a specific buffer and return immediately. This way your user calls won't have to wait on each other. Again, just throwing it out there - these options may or may not fit your requirements.

Comment: buffers that last more than one front facing request (and are not stored in the datastore) can not be guaranteed to be robust.  At any point your instance could be evicted.

Comment: I've dealt with the eviction issue by setting up the shutdown handler, and it works exactly as expected, so I don't lose anything there. I'm just beginning to wonder if there's any good reason for an application to be thread safe at all.